# Date picker in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datepicker

I need to create date picker for my website. Can anyone here suggest me how to do it? Did goggling but I am looking for something simple and easy to be implement. Many thanks

Comment: Well simple and easy is upto you, there are a lot of datepickers you can try like JQuery and most of them are already part of the Related questions on the left part of this screen

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ajax Date Picker [Ajax Date Picker](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) and Also you can use Jquery Date Picker Plug in for that [DateTimePicker using jQuery Plugin](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-DateTimePicker-in-ASP.Net-using-jQuery-Plugin.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check This

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

[Date Picker Server Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42810/ASP-NET-Date-Picker-Server-Control) should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

code on value changed event of datetimepicker1_valuechanged(..........).

```
{

  dateTimePicker1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
}
```

and if u want the value selected in datetimepicker in a textbox.
then drag a textbox above the datetimepicker and do this coding..

```
{

  Textbox1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Ajax Calendar extender**. See this [official web site](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) to download for free and for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JQuery DatePicker` also

http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/